# RecyclerCardview did not show anything

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to pass the data from a weather api and make it into a recyclerView and cardView, but I have no idea why my activity doesn't show anything and i don't know why is not working.

********Here is my code***********

> DailyWeatherInfo.java

```
private Daily mDaily;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private LinearLayoutManager layoutManager;
    private CustomAdapter adapter;
    private List<Daily> data_list;
    private double latitude;
    private double longitude;


    public DailyWeatherInfo() {
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_daily_weather_info);

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        data_list = new ArrayList<>();
        load_weather_info(37.8267,-122.4233);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        adapter = new CustomAdapter(this,data_list);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        //getForcus(37.8267,-122.4233);





    }

    private void load_weather_info(final double latitude, final double longitude) {

        //this.latitude = latitude;
        //this.longitude = longitude;
        AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Void> task = new AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Integer... integers) {

                String apiKey = "--------------------------------";
                String forecastUrl = "https://api.darksky.net/forecast/" + apiKey +
                        "/" + latitude + "," + longitude;
                OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
                Request request = new Request.Builder()
                        .url(forecastUrl)
                        .build();
                try {
                    Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
                    JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response.body().string());

                    for (int i = 0; i<array.length(); i++){
                        JSONObject jsonObject = array.getJSONObject(i);
                        JSONObject daily = jsonObject.getJSONObject("daily");
                        JSONObject mDaily = daily.getJSONObject("data");
                        Daily daily1 = new Daily(mDaily.getString("summary"), mDaily.getString("icon"),
                                mDaily.getDouble("precipProbability"), mDaily.getLong("time"));

                        data_list.add(daily1);

                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                return null;
            }


            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
                super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            }
        };

        task.execute((int) latitude, (int) longitude);
    }
```

> Daily.java

```
public class Daily {

    private String nIcon;
    private String nSummary;
    private String nTimeZone;
    private Long nTimeStamp;
    private Double nPrecipPro;

    public Daily(String nSummary, String nIcon, double nPrecipPro, long nTimeStamp ){
        this.nSummary = nSummary;
        this.nIcon = nIcon;
        this.nPrecipPro = nPrecipPro;
        this.nTimeStamp = nTimeStamp;
    }


    public String getnTimeZone() {
        return nTimeZone;
    }

    public void setnTimeZone(String nTimeZone) {
        this.nTimeZone = nTimeZone;
    }


    public String getnIcon() {
        return nIcon;
    }

    public int getIconId(){
        //clear-day, clear-night, rain, snow, sleet, wind, fog, cloudy, partly-cloudy-day, or partly-cloudy-night
        int iconId = R.drawable.clear_day;

        if (nIcon.equals("clear-day")){
            iconId = R.drawable.clear_day;
        }else if (nIcon.equals("clear-night")) {
            iconId = R.drawable.clear_night;
        }
        else if (nIcon.equals("rain")) {
            iconId = R.drawable.rain;
        }
        else if (nIcon.equals("snow")) {
            iconId = R.drawable.snow;
        }
        else if (nIcon.equals("sleet")) {
            iconId = R.drawable.sleet;
        }
        else if (nIcon.equals("wind")) {
            iconId = R.drawable.wind;
        }
        else if (nIcon.equals("fog")) {
            iconId = R.drawable.fog;
        }
        else if (nIcon.equals("cloudy")) {
            iconId = R.drawable.cloudy;
        }
        else if (nIcon.equals("partly-cloudy-day")) {
            iconId = R.drawable.partly_cloudy;
        }
        else if (nIcon.equals("partly-cloudy-night")) {
            iconId = R.drawable.cloudy_night;
        }
        return iconId;
    }

    public void setnIcon(String nIcon) {
        this.nIcon = nIcon;
    }




    public String getnSummary() {
        return nSummary;
    }

    public void setnSummary(String nSummary) {
        this.nSummary = nSummary;
    }

    public Long getnTimeStamp() {
        return nTimeStamp;
    }

    public String getFormattedTime(){
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a");
        formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(getnTimeZone()));
        Date dateTime = new Date(getnTimeStamp()*1000);
        String timeString = formatter.format(dateTime);
        return timeString;
    }

    public void setnTimeStamp(Long nTimeStamp) {
        this.nTimeStamp = nTimeStamp;
    }

    public Double getnPrecipPro() {
        return nPrecipPro;
    }

    public void setnPrecipPro(Double nPrecipPro) {
        this.nPrecipPro = nPrecipPro;
    }


}
```

> CustomAdapter.java

```
public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private List<Daily> myDaily;



    public CustomAdapter(Context context, List<Daily> myDaily){

        this.context = context;
        this.myDaily = myDaily;
        notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_view,parent,false);

        return new ViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.cSummary.setText(myDaily.get(position).getnSummary());
        holder.cPrecipProability.setText(myDaily.get(position).getnPrecipPro() + "");
        holder.cDate.setText(myDaily.get(position).getFormattedTime());
        holder.cImage.setImageResource(myDaily.get(position).getIconId());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return myDaily.size();
    }


    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView cDate;
        public ImageView cImage;
        public TextView cSummary;
        public TextView cPrecipProability;


        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            cDate = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtDate);
            cSummary = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtSummary);
            cPrecipProability = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtRainChance);
            cImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.weather_icon);
        }
    }
}
```

> card_view xml

Is there anything wrong in my xml file?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/weather_icon"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtDate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/weather_icon"
            android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="18dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/weather_icon"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/weather_icon"
            android:text="2018/04/06,  Friday"
            android:textSize="15dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtSummary"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txtDate"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/txtDate"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="Mostly cloudy throughout the day."
            android:textSize="20dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtRainChance"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/weather_icon"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txtSummary"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/txtSummary"
            android:text="Rain of Chance : 65%" />


    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: print the `size and myDaily.get(position).getnSummary()` in the `Logcat`

Comment: Have you set `LayoutManager`?

Comment: @ADM
Yes, i have set the LayoutManager

Comment: You only created it and did not set . Set `LayoutManager` before setting adapter  and call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` when data is filled to the list .

Comment: @ADM
I already adjust the position of the line, but it's still nor working, am i doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

You just forgot to **`setLayoutManager();`** to your `recyclerView` check it

```
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

**EDIT**

Network operation need some time to perform action  so better to set your set your adapter after you get data from API

Try this

```
    data_list = new ArrayList<>();
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    adapter = new CustomAdapter(this,data_list);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    load_weather_info(37.8267,-122.4233);
```

Change your **`load_weather_info`** method like below code

```
private void load_weather_info(final double latitude, final double longitude) {

        //this.latitude = latitude;
        //this.longitude = longitude;
        AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Void> task = new AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Integer... integers) {

                String apiKey = "--------------------------------";
                String forecastUrl = "https://api.darksky.net/forecast/" + apiKey +
                        "/" + latitude + "," + longitude;
                OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
                Request request = new Request.Builder()
                        .url(forecastUrl)
                        .build();
                try {
                    Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
                    JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response.body().string());

                    for (int i = 0; i<array.length(); i++){
                        JSONObject jsonObject = array.getJSONObject(i);
                        JSONObject daily = jsonObject.getJSONObject("daily");
                        JSONObject mDaily = daily.getJSONObject("data");
                        Daily daily1 = new Daily(mDaily.getString("summary"), mDaily.getString("icon"),
                                mDaily.getDouble("precipProbability"), mDaily.getLong("time"));

                        data_list.add(daily1);

                    }
                 adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                return null;
            }


            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
                super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            }
        };

        task.execute((int) latitude, (int) longitude);
    }
```

Comment: @Nilesh Rathod
I tried to add the line you said, but the activity still not showing anything...

Comment: @Nilesh Rathod
The activity is still not showing anythings, am i missing something here?

Comment: I am very much sure your list is empty.

Answer (score 0):

You have not notified the `adapter` on the change of data.

```
 for (int i = 0; i<array.length(); i++){
                        JSONObject jsonObject = array.getJSONObject(i);
                        JSONObject daily = jsonObject.getJSONObject("daily");
                        JSONObject mDaily = daily.getJSONObject("data");
                        Daily daily1 = new Daily(mDaily.getString("summary"), mDaily.getString("icon"),
                                mDaily.getDouble("precipProbability"), mDaily.getLong("time"));

                        data_list.add(daily1);

                    }
   adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); //notify here
```

Comment: it's not working at too, any other method you suggest ?

Comment: if this is not working you have some issue in adding data check if list is having any data or it is empty. Check the size of list adapter.

Comment: Please share the reason for down voting,

Answer (score 0):

Most of the error are already pointed out. just rectify them.

```
data_list = new ArrayList<>();
recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
adapter = new CustomAdapter(this,data_list);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
load_weather_info(37.8267,-122.4233);
```

Notify adapter as follows.

```
private void load_weather_info(final double latitude, final double longitude) {
    AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Void> task = new AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Void>() {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Integer... integers) {
            String apiKey = "--------------------------------";
            String forecastUrl = "https://api.darksky.net/forecast/" + apiKey +
                    "/" + latitude + "," + longitude;
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url(forecastUrl)
                    .build();
            try {
                Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
                JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response.body().string());

                for (int i = 0; i<array.length(); i++){
                    JSONObject jsonObject = array.getJSONObject(i);
                    JSONObject daily = jsonObject.getJSONObject("daily");
                    JSONObject mDaily = daily.getJSONObject("data");
                    Daily daily1 = new Daily(mDaily.getString("summary"), mDaily.getString("icon"),
                            mDaily.getDouble("precipProbability"), mDaily.getLong("time"));

                    data_list.add(daily1);

                }
                recyclerView.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                });
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        }
    };
    task.execute((int) latitude, (int) longitude);
}
```

**PS:** Here you should make use of `onPostExecute()` to get the returned data set and handle the `Exception`.

Comment: i add the following lines and this error pops out :
Value Forbidden of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray.
Does this mean that i need to convert my String to json array?

Comment: This `Exception` is with parsing of response. Debug the parsing code .

Comment: Sorry, but could you explain what is the meaning of "parsing of response", I am confused.

Comment: I debug the code, and immediately jump to : JSONException e, Is this because there is anything wrong with my JSONE object ?

Comment: one more question, if i did not successfully retrieve data from the api,
does the recyclerCardView still going to appear ?

Comment: Thats outrageous!! How would anyone know that anything wrong with  JSON object or not? Follow some parsing tutorial .